# dequeue and enqueue methods in queue implementation

Tags: java

I was reading about queues in java implementation. I found the following code

```
  public class QueueOfStrings {

    private Node first = null; // least-recently added
    private Node last = null; // most-recently added

    private class Node {

        private String item;
        private Node next;
    }

    // is the queue empty?
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public String dequeue() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Queue underflow");
        }
        String item = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        return item;
    }

    public void enqueue(String item) {
        Node x = new Node();
        x.item = item;
        if (isEmpty()) {
            first = x;
            last = x;
        } else {
            last.next = x;
            last = x;
        }
    }
```

I did rewrite them in my way like this:

```
public String dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Queue underflow");
    } else if (first = last) {
        String f = first.item;
        first = null;
        last = null;
        return f;
    }

    String f = first.item;
    first = first.next;
    return f;

}
public void enqueue(String item) {
    Node x = new Node(item);
    if (first = last = null) {
        first = last = x;
    }
    last.next = x;
    last = x;
}
```

Am I doing right in dequeue() and enqueue() methods?

In the main method should I do like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    QueueOfStrings q = new QueueOfStrings();
    q.enqueue("roro");
    q.enqueue("didi");
    q.enqueue("lala");

    System.out.println(q.dequeue());
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what is meant with "Am I doing write in dequeue() and enqueue() methods?" ? - also, your last if should be if(first==null&&last==null) { instead of if(first=last=null) {

Comment: I meant right.. I found in other codes that they use sometimes `first=last=null`

Comment: this doesn't even compile. What are you trying to do with first=last=null ?

Comment: if(first==null&&last==null)

Comment: that's better !

Comment: Maurice Perry is this correct in my dequeue() method `else if (first = last) {` or should it be like this instead `else if (first == last) {` thanks

Comment: I guess it should be == (otherwise, it will not compile either)

Comment: Maurice Perry is my main method correct? thanks :)

Comment: I suppose so. Are you not trying it?

Comment: Note that you're right to change the code: the original code can produce memory leaks.

Comment: Your enqueue() method is wrong, when you call it on a empty queue it sets first and last to x and then last.next (i.e. x) to x, so the last entry in the queue points back to itself.  You need an else block.

Comment: @JimNicholson Or a return statement inside the if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public String dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Queue underflow");
    } else if (first == last) {
        String f = first.item;
        first = null;
        last = null;
        return f;
    }

    String f = first.item;
    first = first.next;
    return f;

}
public void enqueue(String item) {
    Node x = new Node(item);
    if (first == null && last == null) {
        first = x;
        last = x;
        return; // return back when first node is enqueued
    }
    last.next = x;
    last = x;
}
```

Comment: @Joe When the queue is empty and you enqueue an item, it will go straight into the `if` statement of the `enqueue()` method, right? If you don't put a `return` statement, the code will continue to execute the lines outside of `if` statement. By `return` I mean that "the item has been equeued, end the method here,  and return to where the method was called from"

Comment: @Joe removing the `return` statement works too, but it's more readable that way. ALso, if you remove the return statement, when you enqueue the first item, by the end of the method it will point to itself (which gets fixed when you enqueue the second item but it's a behaviour that you don't want). So, better safe than sorry